# VLC: possible to stream playlist?

Tags: php, vlc, xspf

I've created a PHP script which creates a XSPF playlist automatically from the files inside a folder. Now I was wonder if it's possible to stream the file, so if there are any new files added to the playlist, VLC will pick them up automatically. So I don't have to add the playlist over again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could not get it done with VLC, but I got it working with omxplayer: http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/

I configured a Raspberry Pi which creates automatically a .lst file (with all videos shuffled), from the videos on the USB stick (on every boot the usb in port usb0 will be mounted automatically). After the .lst file is created a bash file will be executed which creates a for loop (for all videos in the .lst file) within a infinite while loop, so the playlist will be executed again after it's finished.